# mail is not working on my PC

Tags: email, ubuntu

Tried to send an email to myself in a bash script from Ubuntu (12.04) command line, it will not send. I even used wireshark to snoop traffic on port 25, don't even see tcp session got established.

```
mail  -s "Subject" xxxxx@yahoo.com < msg.txt
```

It's supposed to be very simple:  just find the server from the email address (xxxxx@yahoo.com), set up a TCP connection and follow the SMTP protocol.  It doesn't even try to establish an TCP connection.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use the sendmail program. It's a lot simpler :)

```
sudo apt-get install sendmail
sudo sendmailconfig
echo testmail | sendmail address@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks @javif89 for the quick reply, I followed through the command `sendmailconfig` with all default choices.  When I run `echo testmail | sendmail xxxx@yahoo.com`,  it gave error message: `sendmail: Cannot open mail:25`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well you can try running the command as sudo. If that doesn't work then you need to configure the /etc/hosts file but for that I need to know if you're running this on a server or just on your home computer :)

Comment: Got the same error when running as root.  I am running it on my home PC (running ubuntu).